# Use Rest API to send attachments

Tags: rest-api, integration

Can we use rest api to send attachments from one SF org to other SF org? If it's not possible from rest then is there any other way to achive this functionality. Please note that S2S and other middleware options can't work in our scenarios.

Comment: and what does the REST API doc say?

Comment: Why is this put on hold?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can send attachment from one SF org to another SF org.

You will need following things to achieve this:

1. A REST web service (HTTP POST) in target org which accepts attachment body as a string.
2. Source org should send the body field of Attachment.

For sending Attachment, create the request body in JSON format using JSONGenerator class and use writeBlobField('body', attachmentBody) method. You may have to use other methods from JSONGenerator class for other data.

When this body is received in web service on target org, you will have to decode it using EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody) and set it to Attachment object's Body field before inserting the Attachment.

Comment: Thanks Ninja. It looks promising and would like implement this idea. Just for curiosity, do you have any sample code which i can try for a small PoC.

Comment: I tried doing this as a PoC as well. I don't have any sample code as of now but it's not much difficult. You can try and I can help if you face any issues. :)